# Does Jquery have the ability to see ids in data passed back from $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `$.get` to return some data:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
  $("#searchResults").html(data);
});
```

When the data is returned it looks like this:

```
 <div class="blah" cid="12344">12344</div>
```

I want to be able to click on this and read the CID:

```
 $('.blah').click(function(){
 $(this).attr('cid');
 });
```

JQuery doesn't seem to handle this... am I right?

Comment: It will handle it if you place it immediately after the .html(data) line.

Comment: the data-* feature of html5 might be better for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using event delegation, you can just change

```
$('.blah').click(function() {
```

to

```
$('#searchResults').on('click', '.blah', function() {
```

and then you'll never have to remove or re-add this event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach that specific event handler after inserting the HTML into the DOM.

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    $("#searchResults").html(data);
    $('.blah').unbind('click').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('cid');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is correct, as long as you don't have additional elements with `class="blah"` outside of the element with `id="searchResults"`.  If you do then the handler will be added more than once.  The solution, then, is to add the handler only to the new elements either by adjusting the selector or applying it to only the newly created elements.

Comment: I'm not saying this doesn't work.... I just couldn't get it to work. I'll keep this in mind when I have more time to reflect, and try again. Thanks!